# Recursively add files by pattern

Tags: git, glob, filepattern

How do I recursively add files by a pattern (or glob) located in different directories?

For example, I'd like to add `A/B/C/foo.java` and `D/E/F/bar.java` (and several other java files) with one command:

```bash
git add '*.java'
```

Unfortunately, that doesn't work as expected.

Comment: It works for me (Mac OS X, Git 1.7.1+). What OS and Git version are you using?

Comment: If you have some (already tracked) `.java` files in your current directory, you may be running into the, er, [complicated wildcard handling between *bash* and the msys command-line “helper”](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/detail?id=257). I am not sure about a solution. You might try multiple layers of quotes: `git add '"*.java"'` (the single quotes are taken by *bash* to prevent glob expansion, the double quotes are taken by the msys layer to prevent glob expansion).

Comment: Thanks for the note. Unfortunately, that doesn't work either. They say the has been fixed, but I already have the latest version.

Comment: possible duplicate of [git: How do I recursively add all files in a directory subtree that match a glob pattern?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221408/git-how-do-i-recursively-add-all-files-in-a-directory-subtree-that-match-a-glob)

Comment: `git add *.java` works for me (on powershell with GitHub client)

Comment: `git add "*.java"` works for me in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

[Sergio Acosta's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2855161) is probably your best bet if some of the files to be added may not already be tracked. If you want to limit yourself to files git already knows about, you could combine `git-ls-files` with a filter:

```bash
git ls-files [path] | grep '\.java$' | xargs git add
```

Git doesn't provide any fancy mechanisms for doing this itself, as it's basically a shell problem: how do you get a list of files to provide as arguments to a given command.

Comment: Thanks! I improved your command slightly and now it's doing what I was looking for: `git ls-files -co --exclude-standard | grep '\.java$' | xargs git add`

Comment: xargs like that did not work for me, given spaces in file names.. what do you think of this version?

git ls-files . | grep -ie '\.bat$' | while read x; do  git add "$x";done

Answer (score 214):

You can use `git add [path]/\*.java` to add java files from subdirectories,
e.g. `git add ./\*.java` for current directory.

From [`git add` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add#_examples):

> Adds content from all `*.txt` files under `Documentation` directory and its subdirectories:
>
> ```
> $ git add Documentation/\*.txt
> ```
>
> Note that the asterisk `*` is quoted from the shell in this example; this lets the command include the files from subdirectories of `Documentation/` directory.

Comment: @MichelKrämer probably it wasn't, but it is now.

Comment: This is the best solution, works in windows as well.

Comment: "asterisk * is quoted from the shell". I think you mean "escaped". In any case, the backslash prevents the shell from expanding it.

Comment: @gwideman I think you're right, but it's not me. It's quote from the docs https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add#_examples

Answer (score 93):

With `zsh` you can run:

```bash
git add "**/*.java"
```

and all your `*.java` files will be added recursively.

Comment: Thanks for that, but I'm working with msysgit on Windows and it has a bash only.

Comment: Well, I see that there is a `zsh` shell for windows... you will do yourself a favour to use it instead of bash, imho.

Comment: The Windows port of zsh is based on a very old version and crashes all the time (for example when I enter `ls`).

Comment: Wow, perfect. I didn't know about that feature!

Comment: This works fine on bash too. Just make sure the files you're targeting are below your current working directory. So you may have to do something like `git add ../../**/*.java` (You don't need quotes surrounding the glob on bash)

Comment: This is nothing to do with zsh. I think this answer misses the point that you want to pass the path with wildcards intact to git and let git process it. You therefore want to prevent whichever shell you are using from expanding the wildcard(s). To do this you need to quote it some way that's appropriate for the shell you're using. See other answers for details.

Answer (score 65):

A bit off topic (not specifically git related) but if you're on linux/unix a workaround could be:

```bash
find . -name '*.java' | xargs git add
```

And if you expect paths with spaces:

```bash
find . -name '*.java' -print0 | xargs -0 git add
```

But I know that is not exactly what you asked.

Comment: Minor issue with this approach -- if you "find" a file that's matched by your .gitignore then git complains that you're trying to add a file you told it to ignore.

Comment: @yoyo - I just added -f on the end, and that fixed that

Comment: @Maslow, that will forcibly add the file, even though it was supposed to be ignored (based on .gitignore). I'd prefer to get the complaint and not add the file (which is the default behaviour.)

Comment: How is this in any way better than letting git perform the wildcard expansion?

Comment: @gwideman git doesn't do the wildcard expansion, the shell does. The original question is just a shell problem as mentioned above. So in a sense, this answer here is quite correct, .gitignore notwithstanding.

Answer (score 12):

[Sergey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9432242/413020) (don't credit me) is working:

> ```
> You can use git add [path]/\*.java
> ```

with a recent git:

```
$git version
git version 1.7.3.4
```

Files for the test:

```
$find -name .git -prune -o -type f -print | sort
./dirA/dirA-1/dirA-1-1/file1.txt
./dirA/dirA-1/dirA-1-2/file2.html
./dirA/dirA-1/dirA-1-2/file3.txt
./dirA/dirA-1/file4.txt
./dirB/dirB-1/dirB-1-1/file5.html
./dirB/dirB-1/dirB-1-1/file6.txt
./file7.txt
```

Git status:

```
$git status -s
?? dirA/
?? dirB/
?? file7.txt
```

Adding *.txt:

```
$git add \*.txt
```

Updated status:

```
$git status -s
A  dirA/dirA-1/dirA-1-1/file1.txt
A  dirA/dirA-1/dirA-1-2/file3.txt
A  dirA/dirA-1/file4.txt
A  dirB/dirB-1/dirB-1-1/file6.txt
A  file7.txt
?? dirA/dirA-1/dirA-1-2/file2.html
?? dirB/dirB-1/dirB-1-1/file5.html
```

Answer (score 11):

As it's not mentioned here, consider also the "[magic signature](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#Documentation/gitglossary.txt-aiddefpathspecapathspec)" `:/` to recursively add anything matching below the project root:

```sh
git add :/*.{java,pom}
```

Tx to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64210713/2586761

Comment: do you mind explaining your pathspec and what it is meant to achieve? I gather you mean to add all files with a `.java` or `.pom` extension, starting from the project root, even though one may be calling `git add` elsewhere. Also, it be great with some explanation/documentation on the curly-braces. I can't get this to work myself

Comment: Hi @CervEd - yup - you've nailed the usecase and interpretation of the pathspec. I'm unsure of the curlies - it may be a bashism (I've just tested it again, and it worked for me on bash), but I didn't find any references specific to git pathspec, sorry ‍♂️ I suggest searches on bash globbing and expansion 

Comment: thanks for the info. It didn't work as expected in CMD which is why I'm guessing this is expanded by the shell before becoming a pathspec for git.

Answer (score 9):

If you are already tracking your files and have made changes to them and now you want to add them selectively based on a pattern, you can use the `--modified` flag

```bash
git ls-files --modified | grep '<pattern>' | xargs git add
```

For example, if you only want to add the CSS changes to this commit, you can do

```bash
git ls-files --modified | grep '\.css$' | xargs git add
```

See `man git-ls-files` for more flags

Answer (score 9):

Just use `git add *\*.java`. This will add all .java files in root directory and all subdirectories.

Comment: Great answer. I did git add */pom.xml to add all files names pom.xml.

Answer (score 5):

Adding a Windows command line solution that was not yet mentioned:

```
for /f "delims=" %G in ('dir /b/s *.java') do @git add %G
```

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to only add files that had a certain string based on `git status`:

`git status | grep string | xargs git add`

and then was able to `git commit -m 'commit msg` to commit all changed files with "string" in the title of the file

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in "[git: How do I recursively add all files in a directory subtree that match a glob pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2222998/6309)", if you properly escape or quote your  pathspec globbing (like `'*.java'`), then yes, git add `'*.java'`

Git 2.13 (Q2 2017) improves that for interactive add:

See [commit 7288e12](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7288e12cce5db87216eba16441a2c37206e5dcad) (14 Mar 2017) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 153e0d7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/153e0d762c15d8a85f0070cd01aff45f5c232e3f), 17 Mar 2017)</sup>

> ### `add --interactive`: do not expand pathspecs with `ls-files`
>
> When we want to get the list of modified files, we first expand any user-provided pathspecs with "`ls-files`", and then feed the resulting list of paths as arguments to "`diff-index`" and "`diff-files`".
>   If your pathspec expands into a large number of paths, you may run into one of two problems:
>
> 1. The OS may complain about the size of the argument
>       list, and refuse to run. For example:
>
>    ```
>    $ (ulimit -s 128 && git add -p drivers)
>    Can't exec "git": Argument list too long at .../git-add--interactive line 177.
>    Died at .../git-add--interactive line 177.
>    ```
>
> That's on the `linux.git` repository, which has about 20K files in the "drivers" directory (none of them modified in this case). The "`ulimit -s`" trick is necessary to show the problem on Linux even for such a gigantic set      of paths.
>   Other operating systems have much smaller limits (e.g., a real-world case was seen with only 5K files on OS X).
>
> 2. Even when it does work, it's really slow. The pathspec
>       code is not optimized for huge numbers of paths. Here's
>       the same case without the ulimit:
>
>    ```
>    $ time git add -p drivers
>      No changes.
>
>    real  0m16.559s
>    user    0m53.140s
>    sys 0m0.220s
>    ```
>
> We can improve this by skipping "`ls-files`" completely, and just feeding the original pathspecs to the diff commands.

Historically the pathspec language supported by "`diff-index`" was weaker, but that is no longer the case.

Answer (score 1):

put line in ~/.gitconfig

`[alias]
         addt = !sh -c 'git ls-files | grep \"\\.$1*\" | xargs git add' -`

If you want to add all modified java file can just do:
`git addt java`

Samely, if you want to add all modified python file can just do:
`git addt py`

Answer (score -1):

###### A variation that I used in a [GNUmakefile](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RandyMcMillan/randymcmillan/master/GNUmakefile)

```make
.PHONY: docs
docs:
    @echo docs
    bash -c "if pgrep MacDown; then pkill MacDown; fi"
    bash -c 'cat $(PWD)/HEADER.md                >  $(PWD)/README.md'
    bash -c 'cat $(PWD)/COMMANDS.md              >> $(PWD)/README.md'
    bash -c 'cat $(PWD)/FOOTER.md                >> $(PWD)/README.md'
    bash -c 'pandoc -s README.md -o index.html'
    bash -c "if hash open 2>/dev/null; then open README.md; fi || echo failed to open README.md"
    #git add --ignore-errors *.md
    git ls-files -co --exclude-standard | grep '\.md/$\' | xargs git
```