# Modifying files in pre-commit hook without having to restage them

Tags: javascript, git, gruntjs, githooks

I just started to use a pre-commit hook in a project, in that script I run some grunt tasks like jshint and jsbeautifier.

The thing is that jsbeautifier does modify the files, so when it does, I have to restage the modified files.

Would it be possible to only have to stage those files only once?

Comment: Why the script could not end with a `git add .`?

Comment: `git add .` might be overkill, but certainly calling `git add` for each file modified by the hook sounds right.

Answer (score 0):

As commented, nothing prevents your script to add the modified files.

You can also [add by type of files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2857909/6309):

```
git ls-files [path] | grep '\.js$' | xargs git add
```

A pre-commit hook like [**`jish/pre-commit`**](https://github.com/jish/pre-commit) ([presented here](http://jish.github.io/pre-commit/))  includes a staging step (in [`lib/pre-commit/utils/staged_files.rb`](https://github.com/jish/pre-commit/blob/5a1eb5e14593b43da1cd2bfcbefff6e66d96a42e/lib/pre-commit/utils/staged_files.rb)).